# Manga about a false hero, Demon grants him 3 wishes

Tags: story-identification, manga

In this manga there is a blonde haired guy that was named hero for something he didn't do. When it was discovered that he was a fraud, they were going to put him to death.

He managed to escape jail with the help of a female, and decided to steal from the castle Treasury because of the humiliation they had put him through. There he found a shovel that could dig through anything and a sealed (think it was under a sword) demon who told him that it could grant 3 wishes.

Wish #1 was to kill the guy who had embarrassed and humiliated him. Magical collars were put on all of the castles citizens, and once all 3 wishes were granted they would all be killed.

Enemy attacked MC ended up killing someone he cares about; MC goes ballistic and reverses time to undo her death and then proceeded to teach this demon a lesson on not messing with people it knows nothing about.

Answer (score 0):

Chillin' in Another World with Level 2 Super Cheat Powers. I been looking for the same thing and just found it when I came across this question

Comment: In which chapters do the plot points described in the question occur? I've skimmed the first dozen or so chapters of this manga and don't recall any of that stuff. Also, the main character has brown (not blond) hair.